# for loop shell script syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")

Tags: sh

for loop shell script syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")

`#!/bin/sh
   PRO="a t d e k "
   for file in $PRO
   do                           #this will be line 6
       echo $file
   done`

output:  line 6: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings in your file, so that the shell sees `do\r` instead of `do`.

Comment: How can i verify that ?

Comment: @chepner, yes .. found a  ^M when i opened it in vi editor. It helped me to solve it. Later used the dos2unix command by referring to http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: As an aside, why would you put the loop tokens in a string variable in this case?  `for file in a t d e k; do` doesn't seem less legible or maintainable at all, and has the distinct advantage that you can have file names with metacharacters etc in them, too (just quote them properly, of course; which you cannot easily do if they have to be in a string).

Comment: Also use proper quoting in `echo "$file"` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a  ^M when i opened it in vi editor. It helped me to solve it.

so it was some thing like this when i opened it in vi editor

```
for file in $PRO
   do^M                           
       echo $file
   done^M
```

Later used the dos2unix command by referring to [computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm)